# ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: ssl

My problem : MAMP does not navigate to local WordPress login page after installation of SSL plugin

Before exporting the contents of my WordPress site to a rental server, I mistakenly activated the SSL plugin, similar to “really simple plugin” that the Japanese rental server company requires when we choose a domain with SSL. After activating this plugin I was supposed to test http and https.  I failed, with error message

SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG

It seems many people get this but not always for the same reasons.  I deleted that plugin file in the "wp-content" file in MAMP and deactivated SSL on the server. Now I get the following error message:

This site can’t provide a secure connection
localhost sent an invalid response.
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

I saw some people suggested deleting some passage in the .htaccess file.  But I did not find the .htaccess file.  This “.htaccess file” solution seems to work if I had already exported the contents of my WordPress site to a rental server, and if I had activated the plugin before I turned on SSL on the rental server side.
Let me clarify my question again,  how can I reach my Wordpress log-in page when my Wordpress content does not exist on the rental server.

One more thing: I have no programming knowledge whatsoever.

Thank you.

Comment: It sounds like SSL wasn't set up properly, or perhaps with old no-longer-supported versions. You could try re-enabling it and then testing the site with something like [Qualys SSL test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) (which is far more thorough than you need) to see if that gives you more information.

Comment: "how can I reach my Wordpress log-in page when my Wordpress content does not exist on the rental server" - I'm not sure I understand: if you mean the whole install is missing, then you probably can't? If you mean you've installed a clean copy of WordPress but not your site content then it should just work I'd think.

Comment: It might also be worth checking wp-config.php: I know some SSL plugins add extra code to map hostnames and the SSL flag somewhere at the very start of the load, and so it might have added some code to the top of wp-config? But I might be remembering that wrong.

Comment: Just to clarify the sequence of events: I created my WordPress site on localhost.  Before moving it to the hosting company's server, I activated the SSL plugin. (Perhaps that was a mistake.)  After activating the plugin, I couldn't access my login page on localhost any more.  Now I'm stuck.  I'm in a different time zone (Japan), so you may not hear from during the next couple of hours.

Comment: Oops, I'd missed that this was all still on localhost. Are you still trying to use http on localhost not https? Is it redirecting you to https even though you now don't want that? You'll have to track that down what's doing the redirect. Can you try accessing a file that should be served statically over HTTP, e.g. http://localhost/wp-content/themes/twentytwenty/style.css to see if it's Apache or WordPress that's doing the redirect?

Comment: Or fixing HTTPS: since this is a mac I think you have openssl installed by default? Can you try `openssl s_client -connect localhost:443` in a terminal to see if that can connect, as it may be more permissive than your browser.

Comment: Or you can always try uploading the site to your host and see if the SSL just works there.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions, Rup. 

Unfortunately, no luck so far. I will try your most recent suggestions (uploading the files to my rental server and seeing if the SSL just works there) as soon as my domain has been re-added to the rental server and shows up in the control panel again.

Comment: A follow-up question: 
1. would uploading the site to the host and checking if SSL just works there, as you suggest, solve the localhost redirect issue or would it just circumvent it?  
2. If the latter, wouldn't I still have to solve the localhost issue?
I tried your first two suggestions but without success.  
I should also say that I'm a total newbie and hosting company instruction is not clear. 
3. Is file transfer to the server-side possible even if I don't have anything on the hosting company's server yet, and I can't access my site on localhost?

Comment: 1) no, but it if it does work then it'd look like the local Apache configuration was wrong, not necessarily WordPress. (And it'd get the site into a state you could work on it, albeit hosted remotely.)

Comment: "I tried your first two suggestions but without success." - OK, assuming you meant 1) reading style.css from localhost, what did happen? Did you get a 404 not found whilst still on HTTP (unlikely), redirected to HTTPS but then the same connection error (= either Apache is doing the redirects, not WordPress, or you didn't have the default TwentyTwenty theme on disk), or something else?

Comment: and if you meant 2) connecting to your server with openssl s_client didn't work at all, then your localhost HTTPS server is broken or not running at all, because it's not serving TLS/SSL at all. Hopefully the error message you got was informative.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to upload files to the hosting company whether or not you have a working WordPress site at either end. They should be willing to help you with this.

Comment: However unless you have specific error messages to show us to solve then this is likely the limit of what we can do for you remotely. If you're still stuck I'd suggest starting again with a fresh installation of MAMP and WordPress, but save the database and theme to restore to that instance so you don't lose your content.

Comment: Thanks again for your responses.  I'm trying to upload the files to the server.  I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: I tried uploading my files to the server, as you suggested.  After activating SSL on the server, I installed FileZilla.  But when I clicked on the "Connect" button in the Site Manager window, I got the following error message:
Status:       Connecting to olivemole2.sakura.ne.jp...
Response:  fzSftp started, protocol_version=9
Command: open "olivemole2@olivemole2.sakura.ne.jp" 22
Command: Pass: **********
Error:         Authentication failed.
Error:         Critical error: Could not connect to server

Comment: I next installed an empty WordPress instance on the server with the Quick Install method. Although I am using an English language WordPress locally, I could install only a Japanese language Wordpress on the server.  After I did this, I could see a .htaccess file on my local machine.  I deleted the part that was enforcing SSL.  After that I was able to access my website on localhost again. So I thought that I could now use the plugins to upload my files to the server.   
But when I went to localhost:8888/wp-login.php, the login page had changed from English to Japanese.

Comment: When I entered my ID and password for my local WordPress site and clicked on the button, the URL in the address bar changed to

<my_domain_name.com>/wp-login.php

Upon entering my server-side WordPress ID and password, I got to the dashboard of my empty WordPress instance on the server.  I  still cannot access the dashboard of my local WordPress site, although I changed the password from PHPMYADMIN at the local-side.
Thank you.

Comment: You'll have to talk to your web hosts about SFTP access. The localhost issue is now probably the site URL - WordPress still thinks it's at the real URL, not localhost. You can either change this in the database or by adding a local site URL override e.g. in wp-config.php that you don't upload to the real site: https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/

Comment: I was finally able to access the dashboard of my local WordPress site again after opening phpMyAdmin, selecting Wordpress > wp-options, and changing the site URL back to "localhost" (it was "localhost" originally, but I had changed it to <my_domain_name>).  But now I couldn't access the dashboard of my hosted WordPress site any more.  After creating a new user with new ID, I could access the dashboard on the server again. (Previously, I used the same ID and PW on localhost and on the server.)

Comment: Yes, the site URL needs to be different between the two.